# Invariance of maximally entangled state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-information, hilbert-space

How can the equality below hold? If I have a maximally entangled qudit state $\lvert \Phi\rangle_{AB}$ and any $d\times d$ matrix $M$, then it is claimed that 
$$ (M_A\otimes I_B)\lvert \Phi\rangle_{AB} = (I_A\otimes M_B^T)\lvert\Phi\rangle_{AB}$$

I can see that this works for qubits and using the Pauli spin operators, but I am not seeing it in the general case.

Comment: It's important to note that this only works for one particular maximally entangled state $\left|\Phi\right>$ (the one used in udrv's answer (and its scalar multiples)). If $\left|\Phi\right>$ is any other maximally entangled state this relation will be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the maximally entangled state be
$$
|\Phi\rangle_{AB} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}} \sum_{k=1}^D{|k_A\otimes k_B\rangle}
$$
Then
$$
(M_A\otimes I_B) |\Phi\rangle_{AB} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}} \sum_{k=1}^D{\left( M_A|k_A\rangle\right)\otimes |k_B\rangle} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}} \sum_{j,k=1}^D{\left( \langle j|M|k\rangle|j_A\rangle\right)\otimes |k_B\rangle} = \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}} \sum_{j,k=1}^D{|j_A\rangle \otimes\left( \langle j|M|k\rangle |k_B\rangle\right)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}} \sum_{j,k=1}^D{|j_A\rangle \otimes\left( \langle k|M^T|j\rangle |k_B\rangle\right)} = \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{D}} \sum_{j=1}^D{|j_A\rangle \otimes\left( M_B^T |j_B\rangle\right)} = (I_A \otimes M_B^T)|\Phi\rangle_{AB}
$$

Comment: Thank You for the reply. One more question, can you please explain the expansion on the third equation of the first row. Seems, like you have expanded |K> in the basis of |J>?

Comment: Actually it's an expansion of $M_A|k_A\rangle$: $$M_A|k_A\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^D{|j_A\rangle\langle j_A | M_A | k_A\rangle} = \sum_{j=1}^D{|j_A\rangle\langle j| M | k\rangle}$$where the last form takes into account that the matrix elements of $M$ on given states are system-independent.